# Firefox 29: Can any page open my browser menus?

Tags: security, firefox

I installed firefox 29.  The curious thing I noticed is that the updated browser's page https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/29.0/whatsnew/?oldversion=28.0 was able to open menus in my browser.

How can a website open menus in my browser?  Is it domain restricted only to firefox or can I use this feature?  If any one can do this, wont it be a security issue?